# Not receiving user details on Cognito Post Confirmation Trigger

Tags: java, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework, serverless, amazon-cognito-triggers

I have created user pool on cognito, I want to trigger a lambda function post the user is confirmed his identity. I am using Post Confirmation as trigger from my aws cognito user pool. What i observe is when the user is confirming is identity i am able to get the request in my lambda function. But i am not getting any user details or user attributes in my lambda function request body comes as null. Where as if i convert the same lambda to to a HTTP event and pass object from postman i am getting the request Body. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Language used is Java

Answer (score 0):

we would need more details about how you are testing the confirmation flow + how your lambda is configured,

in the meantime, I created a working example with Java 8 + Serverless Framework with Amazon Cognito in CloudFormation, you can see the details here:

https://github.com/oieduardorabelo/2021-03-19-cognito-java-post-signup-confirmation

Pardon my Java, I know nothing about it!

I'm explaining how I tested the signup flow and the output in CloudWatch includes all necessary user details.

I hope it can help you debug your application!